# PHP / MYSQL: Creating a query that can search data from 2 columns but can be optional to 2 or 1

Tags: php, mysql

based on my question, I have a table named tbl_programme. That table has 3 columns which are ID, session, and class. Now, I want to create an MYSQL query for a PHP website that can display the data based on the 3 columns, which are session, class, and course.

From that 2 columns, it's not compulsory to use them where clause for all 2 columns, it can be two columns or one column only. Below is my current query:

```
SELECT * from tbl_programme where session = '$session' AND class = '$class';
```

[image]

If I run the query with only put data for class and course, it still does not display the specific data that I want. I try to change the use of OR, but still the same. Can anyone help me to solve this?

Comment: Try this 

SELECT * from tbl_programme where session LIKE '%$session%' OR class LIKE '%$class%';

Comment: What's the default value of your parameters?

Comment: @Arian is still the same. when i put data class =  T6 and session =  noon, it will display att T6 data with All session, not T6 and noon

Comment: @RatuBatuHamloKoto please update your question and add your mysql table with some sample data.

Comment: @Arian. Done. can check above

Comment: @RatuBatuHamloKoto can you try my query but just replacing OR with AND

Comment: @RatuBatuHamloKoto SELECT * FROM `tbl_programme` WHERE class LIKE '%T01%' AND session LIKE '%noon%' this query works for me. [screenshot](https://prnt.sc/pjPbZqC8fVlr)

Comment: @Arian still cannot. Like i mentioned at my question, if i out two param, then can display result. But just now if i put only class = T01 and session is empty, no result display. suppose it will display T01 data